# jquery - show where class is not

Tags: html, jquery

How do I show the next element which NOT contains the class ".hidden"?

JQUERY

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn_next", function(e){

    // SHOW NEXT SECTION
    $(this).parents('.form_section').next().show();

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="form_section">CONTENT HERE 1 <a class="btn_next">NEXT</a></div>
<div class="form_section hidden" style="display: none">CONTENT HERE 2 <a class="btn_next">NEXT</a></div>
<div class="form_section" style="display: none">CONTENT HERE 3 <a class="btn_next">NEXT</a></div>
<div class="form_section hidden" style="display: none">CONTENT HERE 3 <a class="btn_next">NEXT</a></div>
```

Comment: `$(this).parents('.form_section').next(':not(.hidden)').show();`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this: `siblings(':not(.hidden)')` selects all siblings that don't have the class `hidden` and `first()` selects the first one of these siblings.

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn_next", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('.form_section').siblings(':not(.hidden)').first().show();
});
```

For reference: [jQuery not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/), [jQuery siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/), [jQuery first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) and working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdcxr9qe/).

Comment: hi, in your case ":not" refer to "next+not contain class"?

Comment: @Roi No, it doesn't refer to the next element because $(this).parents(".form_selection") is already the element for which it should be checked if it also contains the class "hidden".

Comment: ok, but button "btn_next" should show only the next "form_section" which NOT contain class "hidden". I edited the code above

Comment: @Roi I've just adjusted my answer for this requirement, it was a misunderstanding.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but does your code show only the next ".form_section" div or all? I would like to keep all not visible except the next "form_section" without the "hidden" class...

Comment: OK, i think i found the answer - `$(this).parents('.form_section').nextAll(':not(.condition_sec)').first().show();`

Comment: @Roi You're right. My answer works for your example where btn_next is the first button, but in case the button is elsewhere nextAll would only select the next form_section elements where siblings would also select the previous elements with the class form_section.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the below code:

```
$(this).parents('.form_section').not('.hidden').show();
```

This will get your parent element of given name and in that itt will find elment which does not have `hidden` class.

Comment: hi, in your case ":not" refer to "next+not contain class"?